# Binding Energy of an Electric Dipole

Tags: electrostatics, electricity

My question is structured in two parts:

1. Is there any way to isolate the charges of an electric dipole?
2. What is the binding energy of an electric dipole?
           To put it in another way, is there any dipole binding energy so that if an amount of energy above that binding energy is applied to the dipole, the dipole is split into its constituent charges.

Answer (score 1):

An electric dipole is some configuration of charge, namely two opposite charges separated by a distance. However, such a description is an effective, quite general description for various physical situations.

For example, Carbon monoxide $CO$ can be described as a dipole. Relative to the oxygen-side of the bond there is slightly more negative charge located near the carbon side, which makes the oxygen side slightly positive and hence it is a dipole. As you see the answers to your question depends on the physical model of the dipole.

Comment: Is there any way to find the dipole binding energy of a specific dipole?